# Best equivalence of #define in C++

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces

Usually I use `#define MY_PARRENT_THE_FIRST 1` in order to use less memory.

I searched for a best equivalence in C++ about this and I found two:

First is by using enums:

```
enum class MyParrent : char 
{
   theFirst = 1, 
   theSecond = 6, 
   theThird = 64
}
```

Second using namespace and variables:

```
namespace MyParrent 
{
    char const theFirst (1);
    char const theSecond (6);
    char const theThird (64);
}
```

However I was unable to find out if any of these is using no memory footprint as the `#define MY_PARRENT_THE_FIRST 1` statement.

Which is the best practice to achieve the same no memory footprint in C++ (inline insert of the value instead of allocating memory and inserting the value there)?

Comment: `static const int MY_PARRENT_THE_FIRST = 1;` shouldn't occupy any space in memory.

Comment: can't it be done inside a namespace like the second version but with static in front?

Comment: Sure, it can appear in the `namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

Types don't take run-time memory, only values do. This is because the resulting executable does not need to store everything about types, but it is required to store most variables. Your `enum MyParrent` is a type and does not take memory, but a value of type `enum MyParrent` takes one byte of memory, because the underlying type of `enum MyParrent` is a `char`. When you define variables like in your second example, this takes memory for sure.

PS: Your definition of `MY_PARRENT_THE_FIRST` expands to an integer literal `1` and might in some cases take even memory at runtime, because integer literals are of type `int` or of even some wider integer type. You can verify this by:

```
auto const var = MY_PARRENT_THE_FIRST;
static_assert(sizeof(var) > sizeof(MyParrent), "");
```